# A comic about a duck who learns to fight with a feather without realizing he's made of feathers

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember checking a comic book out of the library sometime in 2003-2010 about a duck who has a real jerk of a dad so he goes off to learn how to fight from a blind master (a mouse perhaps?). One of his fellow students has the quote "My opponents are unworthy". A key point was that he learned how to destroy someone with just a feather, but when he goes to fight his dad, he loses his feather and it seems like he's going to lose until he realizes he's made of feathers.

There is magic all over the place, I think there may have even been a prophecy of some kind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This might sound like an odd question, but are there any explicit science fiction or fantasy elements in this story, aside from the inclusion of animals that behave like humans? The policy on this site is that that alone doesn't qualify a story as sci-fi or fantasy.

Comment: Yes, there is magic all over the place, I think there may have even been a prophecy of some kind? Definitely magic happening though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_(comics)?

Comment: @Valorum YES, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 4):

This is [Dungeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_(comics)) (Donjon), a French comic.

> The series is a parody of sword and sorcery conventions in general,
> and specifically of the role-playing game Dungeons & Dragons. All of
> the characters are either anthropomorphic animals or other strange
> creatures. The "dungeon" of the title is, in the original series, a
> business establishment run by a mild-mannered chicken, where heroes
> come in search of adventure and treasure and invariably die. The
> timeline in the main continuity is described as the stages of day; the
> series that lead up to the dungeon's creation are described in the
> Potron-Minet (dawn) segment, the castle's glory days are described as
> its Zénith (zenith), and its inevitable decay is described in the
> Crépuscule (twilight) stories.
>
> [image]

Comment: Were there a million goblins at the last door?

Comment: @Adamant - I'm just trying to find out. This is the next panel; https://virgil.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/0/2/1902829/9798932_orig.jpg?549

Comment: @Adamant - Surprisingly I haven't been able to find it online except at exorbitant cost. Tempted to ask a question about it :-)

Comment: I found something online but I'm having a hard time finding the exact panels from this answer. Uh

Comment: According to the French Wikipedia, "Dungeon Zenith (level 1 to 100) tells the story of how Herbert came in posession of the different items of destiny", so I'm guessing that's where the panel comes from. Edit: Dungeon Zenith Vol. 1, page 80, is where they arrive at the 1st door.

Comment: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/9XwBMEPwp6z5hYwxQFspkeoxmBnUi9WvUJPkudOsWhAcYRIwGnrUFeWpxspehFArGFhkJ9lFZRFpp7_KLnoiedHxQfJfDy3d9vAfkwjzsY-DN0LmHYv0ZEq_EM77kYVD-pSQEyTOLg=s1600?rhlupa=MmEwMTpjYjA0OmJhMTo4MTAwOmQ4YWI6N2RlMzpkMDJhOmU0NjU=&rnvuka=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFgxMTsgTGludXggeDg2XzY0OyBydjoxMDkuMCkgR2Vja28vMjAxMDAxMDEgRmlyZWZveC8xMTcuMA

Comment: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/7E-wH5O4atcS6BTNmc8fkB-Wr4d2Zz79bFs4h34HNgQsZZtfydqTrjZWGe24VJ3_1jPKpiYYN0AkUIHvmPhqZaHAcicyFBcOpdaMt7I7U-xlRYiQv3Ny-KXh2KzAF6tLXndSJf5k4Q=s1600?rhlupa=MmEwMTpjYjA0OmJhMTo4MTAwOmQ4YWI6N2RlMzpkMDJhOmU0NjU=&rnvuka=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFgxMTsgTGludXggeDg2XzY0OyBydjoxMDkuMCkgR2Vja28vMjAxMDAxMDEgRmlyZWZveC8xMTcuMA

Comment: I'm afraid that's the last we see of these doors.